# OS X 10.11 unable to press "allow" on Keychain Access dialogs

Tags: macos, icloud, password, keychain

I'm running into an issue where keychain password verification box does not verify password - does not shake for incorrect password and nothing happens when I press "allow". I'm using iCloud keychain.

**What could make the Keychain Access wants to... dialog box to not verify the password?**

Nothing happens when I press "Allow" with password enters. The box does not shake when password is incorrect:
[image]

Comment: I have the exact same problem :( anyone?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33311873/1214800 OMG I want to smash things!

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213124/unable-to-export-p12-certificate-from-keychain-access/214851#214851

Comment: I came across this issue as well, it turned out that I had to disconnect my Wacom Tablet, and use a regular mouse (Magic Mouse in my case) in order for the 'allow' or 'always allow' buttons to work. Such a weird bug to diagnose. Luckily I didn't have to turn off any of the apps in the Settings -> Security -> Accessibility area.

Comment: This issue is caused by a new Apple restriction on Keychain whereby scripts and apps will no longer have remote access to Keychain functions like export. I would have left this as an answer, but this thread has been protected from spammy answers that contribute no worth to the question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I encountered this same issue today. I could not "Allow" or "Always Allow" any programs, nor could I confirm my password in any dialogues. The interface wouldn't shake, even if I had entered the incorrect password.

I use Synergy to facilitate programming over several different computers. My mouse and keyboard do not belong to the Mac OSX device. I was able to hit the "Allow" button once I used a mouse actually hooked up the Mac OSX device.

In general, try turning off any virtual or physical KVM services and use the Mac mouse/keyboard directly.

Hopefully this can help you or someone else who comes here looking for help.

Comment: I found with Remote Desktop running, having a mouse connected (and watching on the nearby remote screen) still exhibits the problem. Even connecting a screen and keyboard while remote desktop is observing presented the issue. I removed remote desktop and tried from VNC - same problem. However, having VNC running, and accessing from the local installed keyboard is OK. This sucks!

Comment: @BobChao87's answer is right. I had same problem when MagicPrefs program (used to customize experience of Apple Magic Mouse) was launched. If you're using MagicPrefs, simply quit this program and everything will work well.

Comment: @KirkHammett You are a lifesaver. I had MagicPrefs installed and that was the problem. Is there any solution to this? I use many of MagicPrefs features, so I really want to have it enabled and run. (And I think no other similar software would work, right?)

Comment: @Behdad I think, we may contact MagicPrefs directly to ask if they can warn users about this problem. UPD: contacted developers regarding this question.

Comment: @Behdad For now, you can always just turn it on and off as you find interactions that require the direct keyboard and mouse as a workaround until Apple and/or MagicPrefs fix the issue. Given how many different things are having an issue though, sounds like Apple might have introduced an ... interesting security feature.

Comment: The issue was a little more difficult for me because I didn't have MagicPrefs or BetterTouchTools (or something of the like) installed. My problem ended up being a Wacom Tablet driver. I thought it would only be running when I had a tablet plugged in, but it runs all the time. Once I killed the driver's processes, it started working again.

Comment: Wow.. all this time I have been cursing that my reinstalled OSX that had the same problems as prior to me wiping everything had the same issues and I put it down to an OSX bug and it turned out to be synergy all along -_- Thanks you @BobChao87

Comment: Can confirm I also use synergy

Comment: Bless you @KirkHammett for saving me from sheer madness!

Comment: @KirkHammett I have MagicPrefs and it wouldn't allow me to 'Allow', nor with the touchPad, nor with the external mouse. But hitting <enter> without moving the mouse worked

Comment: My problem is that I can no longer, for the life of me, bring back the dialog that has the "Always Allow" button. I uninstalled this VPN app several times, removed its files in various Library folders, removed its credentials in the Keychain agent, but nope, the app keep asking me for my password each time I want to VPN. In Keychain Agent I keep trying to switch "Access Control" to "Allow all applications to access this item" on the VPN credentials, to no effect, it reverts to "Confirm before allowing access"...

Comment: @sebastien.b It sounds like you might be having a different issue than that discussed in this thread. The recommendation here is that you should turn off any input modifiers (Synergy, MagicPrefs, remote desktops, _etc_) and then approve access to the more sensitive security location. If this doesn't solve your problem, you may wish to open a new question since VPNs _out of_ your machine wouldn't be triggering the behaviour described here.

Comment: @BobChao87 the problem was the same, I was indeed using Remote Desktop to install the app that offered "Allow" or "Always Allow" but I did not find the answer here until much later -- by that time I had blamed macOS and *killed* the app. When I restarted the app, it seems it had defaulted to "Allow" on its own, and I have absolutely no idea how to bring back the dialog that would let me pick "Always Allow". (BTW VPN will try to auto-connect if its Network interface has "Connect on Demand" set to On and *any* app on the machine is trying to access something on the net).

Answer (score 3):

For me, I had to go to `System Preferences` -> `Security & Privacy` -> `Privacy`.

On the left, click on `Accessibility`, then on the right side uncheck every checkbox. This resolves the problem. For me, I had Steam (from VALVe) running and Karabiner (keyboard key editor) which also was allowed to control the computer.

Comment: That's odd. I have a bunch of items in this privacy section yet my keychain is still filly functional. Are you able to detect a console error message showing what is logged when the bad extensions are enabled? I have eight enabled apps to control and one disabled. Of course, when I remote control this mac - that breaks keychain for "security reasons" - but not all apps in Accessibility seem to cause keychain to prevent synthetic actions.

Comment: I couldn't find any console errors. Steam seems to be the problem but I wasn't able to confirm it.

Comment: +1 This solved it for me. Thanks! Dropbox was one of the programs in that list for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just got this fixed. I use a plugin called [SmoothMouse](http://smoothmouse.com) that improves acceleration of trackpad and mouse. It likely integrates with the accessibility APIs in OS X and thus triggers the same behavior as screensharing. Disabling the plugin resolved the problem.

You can see the sister StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33311873/1214800) as well.

Comment: I was having the same problem using a Wacom tablet with El Capitan. Disconnecting the tablet allowed me to export my certificates.

Comment: @MiKL, I had the same issue, through testing various harward configurations came to the realization that my Wacom tablet was the issue. :/

Comment: I also tried installing the latest drivers from the Wacom site, but that did not resolve the issue. :(

Comment: I confirm this appears to have resolved my issues.   I was using MagicPrefs and when I quit it is too resolved the unable to press Allow.  (I could use <space> to press Allow but never the mouse or the Always Allow.  Deny always worked.