# Unable to export .p12 certificate from Keychain Access

Tags: macos, password, keychain, certificate

I'm trying to export a Developer certificate from Keychain Access. I've followed all the instructions and got to the point where I need to `enter the "login" keychain password`.

However, when I enter this password and press `Allow`, nothing happens.

I've checked the password multiple times. The Keychain Access is set to `Keychains = login` and `Category = My Certificates`. I've tried with other categories too.

Comment: It's definitely password typo. Check input language probably? Also, keep in mind, that keychain password is not alway equal to you administrator password. If you logged in from different user or exported keychain from somewhere else - the passwords may not match

Comment: But I can open and lock the login keychain using the same password. Can it be a different password than that?

Comment: No, if you're locking and unlocking keychain - the password fits. Strange then

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem when logged in via VNC / remote desktop - it appears that if your mac detects a 'security risk' it will prevent you from pressing the "Always Allow" / "Allow" buttons.

No error message is shown and the box doesn't shake (although the button does highlight blue when clicked.)

The same issue seems to exist with KVM programs such as Synergy.

To solve the problem, simply log in to your mac using a physical keyboard and mouse, ensure remote desktop / KVM connections are turned off and try clicking the "Allow" button again

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208704/os-x-10-11-unable-to-press-allow-on-keychain-access-dialogs

Comment: This resolved my issue. I was using Sharemouse for input to the Mac.

Comment: You will need to also restart your machine after disconnecting the VNC session (El Capitan 10.11.1)

Comment: Oh weird - mine worked straight away :) YMMV I guess

Comment: Very Important Point from Nathan's post: The plugin's MagicPref's & SmoothMouse will trigger the same security mechanism - quit them and try again. Hopefully this helps someone!

Comment: This happened for me when using GoToMeeting screen sharing. Very annoying without any error message.

Comment: srsly.. WTF Apple?! I already completely created a new login.keychain.. before I found this post. They could have put an error message at least.

Comment: This is an absolute nightmare for developers who screen share into an OS X box and need to key sign something. Sometimes developers won't have physical access to the machine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to go to `System Preferences` -> `Security & Firewall` -> `Privacy`.

On the left, click on `Accessibility`, then on the right side uncheck every checkbox. This resolves the problem. For me, I had Steam (from VALVe) running and Karabiner (keyboard key editor) which also was allowed to control the computer.

Comment: I'm using synergy and have done same things in Privacy, but didn't receive right to press Allow. Probably I need a couple of reboots